# iterating through list of tuples in python and choosing certain elements

Tags: python

I have a list

```
f_list = ["[('TTATGCTAAGTATC', 8)]", "[('TTATGCTAAGTATC', 8)]", "[('AGCTCCCCGTTTTC', 1)]", "[('AGCTCCCCGTTTTC', 35), ('TTCATTCCTCTCTC', 1)]", "[('TTATGCTAAGTATC', 4), ('TTACGCTACTCACC', 1)]"]
```

I want to make a new list with elements whose second element of a tuple is greater than 10.

I tried

```
for e in f_list:
    [item for item in f_list if e[1] >= 10]
```

But this does not work. The expected output is a list like

```
f_new = ["nil","nil","[('AGCTCCCCGTTTTC', 35)]"]
```

Comment: you have strings not tuples

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it, but it works:

```
f_list = [
    "[('TTATGCTAAGTATC', 8)]",
    "[('TTATGCTAAGTATC', 8)]",
    "[('AGCTCCCCGTTTTC', 1)]",
    "[('AGCTCCCCGTTTTC', 35)]",
    "[('TTCATTCCTCTCTC', 1)]",
    "[('TTATGCTAAGTATC', 4)]",
    "[('TTACGCTACTCACC', 1)]"
]

f_new = []

for i in f_list:

    if int(i.split(',')[1].split(')')[0]) >= 10:
        # Adds all items that satisfy your requirements
        f_new.append(i)
    else:
        # Adds 'nil' for the items that
        # do not satisfy your requirements
        f_new.append("nil")

print f_new
```

**output**

```
['nil', 'nil', 'nil', "[('AGCTCCCCGTTTTC', 35)]", 'nil', 'nil', 'nil']
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Padraic, your list is a little strange. You have quotation marks where you don't need them, and put each tuple in a separate list with only one element. If you can clean up your original list, this should work the way you expect:

```
f_list = [('TTATGCTAAGTATC', 8), ('TTATGCTAAGTATC', 8), ('AGCTCCCCGTTTTC', 1), ('AGCTCCCCGTTTTC', 35), ('TTCATTCCTCTCTC', 1), ('TTATGCTAAGTATC', 4), ('TTACGCTACTCACC', 1)]

f_new = []

for tupl in f_list:
    if tupl[1] > 10:
        f_new.append(tupl)
    else:
        f_new.append("nil")

print(f_new)
```

Output:

```
['nil', 'nil', 'nil', ('AGCTCCCCGTTTTC', 35), 'nil', 'nil', 'nil']
```

If you cannot change your original list and only need the elements that match your requirements, Jape's answer will do it for you.